# gdb get line number of a demangled function name with one command

Tags: c++, gdb

i cannot get the source line from gdb with one gdb command for a c++ demangled function name. but for a mangled name, it works.

a sample c++ app:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    virtual void print()
    {
        std::cout << "hello\n";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    A a;
    a.print("hello");
}
```

build `g++ test.cpp -g -o test.bin`
get the line number in gdb of a mangled name (one command):

```
gdb test.bin
>info line *(_ZN1A5printEv+20)
Line 8 of "test.cpp" starts at address 0x1274 <A::print()+16> and ends at 0x1287 <A::print()+35>.
```

but when i try to get the line number with the demangled name  :

```
>info line *(A::print()+20)
Cannot resolve method A::print to any overloaded instance
```

it works only in 2 steps:

```
> info line A::print()
Line 6 of "test.cpp" starts at address 0x1264 <A::print()> and ends at 0x1274 <A::print()+16>.
>info line *(0x1264+20)
Line 8 of "test.cpp" starts at address 0x1274 <A::print()+16> and ends at 0x1287 <A::print()+35>.
```

is there a way to get the line number with one gdb command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow GDB to recognize `A::print()` as a single symbol, enclose it in single quotes

```
info line *('A::print()'+20)
```